# Get button's id in SQL query using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table with my projects. Last cell contains button SHOW IMAGE which should load an image url based on data from DB (project_id = image name. for example "4189.jpg").

How could I modify the code to get dynamic id when I click on specific SHOW IMAGE button? Actually I just need to get id value of clicked button and set this value as `$image_id` variable.

HTML STRUCTURE

```
<table class="table table-hover all-projects text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">project's date</th>
      <th scope="col">quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">order no</th>
      <th scope="col">image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>27.09.2018</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>15092018</td>
    <td><span id="1634" class="d-none display btn btn-info">SHOW IMAGE</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15.06.2018</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>2062018</td>
    <td><span id="4189" class="d-none display btn btn-info">SHOW IMAGE</span></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

AJAX REQUEST:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".display").click(function() {                

     $.ajax({    //AJAX REQUEST FOR show-image.php
       type: "GET",
       url: "modules/show-image.php",             
       dataType: "html",        
       success: function(response){                    
           $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
       }

   });
});
});
</script>
```

show-image.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$get_user = $_SESSION['user'];

include("../db-conn.php");
mysqli_select_db($con,"projects");
$image_id = "4189"; //GET ID FROM BUTTON'S ID, NOW IT'S STATIC
$result=mysqli_query($con, "select * from projects where user = '$get_user' and project_id = '$image_id'");


  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  { 

  echo '<img class="img-fluid" src="../../img/projects/'. md5("$get_user") . "/" .  $row["project_id"] .'.jpg" alt="" />';

  }
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Hi, you should put the ID on the Ajax get call, after that you can dynamically read the id from php with $_GET['myVar']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you can using onclick on`show image`

on html,

```
 <table class="table table-hover all-projects text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">project's date</th>
      <th scope="col">quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">order no</th>
      <th scope="col">image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>27.09.2018</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>15092018</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showImage(1634)" id="1634" class="d-none display btn btn-info">SHOW IMAGE</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15.06.2018</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>2062018</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showImage(4189)" id="4189" class="d-none display btn btn-info">SHOW IMAGE</a></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

on js,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showImage(id){
     $.ajax({    //AJAX REQUEST FOR show-image.php
       type: "GET",
       url: "modules/show-image.php?image_id="+id,             
       dataType: "html",      
       success: function(response){                    
           $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(jqXHR);
       }
   });
}
</script>
```

on php,

```
<?php 
session_start();
$get_user = $_SESSION['user'];

include("../db-conn.php");
mysqli_select_db($con,"projects");
$image_id = $_GET['image_id']; //GET ID FROM BUTTON'S ID, NOW IT'S STATIC
$result=mysqli_query($con, "select * from projects where project_id = '$image_id'");


  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  { 

  echo '<img class="img-fluid" src="../../img/projects/'. md5("$get_user") . "/" .  $row["project_id"] .'.jpg" alt="" />';

  }

?>
```

may it can help you

Comment: happy to hear that :)

Comment: Some projects are duplicated in DB, do you have any idea how DISTINCT the results from DB? Because right now some projects show twice the same image.

Comment: may I know the query that you are using ?

Comment: `select * from projects where user = '$get_user' and project_id = '$image_id`
Unfortunatelly this one did not work:
`select distinct * from projects where user = '$get_user' and project_id = '$image_id`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your AJAX request to also send the value of the `id` attribute ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.display').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'modules/show-image.php',
        data: {
          imageId: $(this).attr('id'),
        }
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response) {
          $('#responsecontainer').html(response);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

... and include and escape it in your PHP script:

```
$image_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['imageId']);
```

Also check if it's set, otherwise it may cause some errors.